# Docker on Windows 10. Is it an Inbound Rule or Outbound Rule?

Tags: windows-10, firewall, docker

I am trying to share hard drives with Docker, but I am getting this error:

[image: docker error]

I went to the [documentation here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#firewall-rules-for-shared-drives), but it isn't clear on whether it is an Outbound Rule or an Inbound Rule that I need to create in my Windows Firewall.

My networking knowledge isn't great, so it isn't obvious to me which it should be. Also, I assume it is the Port option that I want, I then go ahead tell it the port `445` as per the documentation, but then I am asked about the Domain with the options being Private, Public ...etc I am not sure what to select there either.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can see your network location by **network and sharing center**.

[image]

Then you can set rules to open `tcp port 445` as following steps.

1. Right click `Inbound rules`, click `New`
2. Click `Custom`
3. In the new Window, select `All programs`, type the `specified program path`, or `Services`
4. Then you can select `tcp port 445` in `Local port` and `Remote port`, you can use any
5. Then select Ip `Scope` as your requirements, you can use both any Ip address and any Ip daress
6. Select `Allow the Connection` or `Allow the connection if it is secure`
7. Select your `profile`, you can choose your current profile(As we see at the beginning), or select all
8. Then type the rule name(This is dependent on yourself)
9. After setting **inbound rule**, take the same action to create a **outbound rule**.